# RXJS: merge streams and utilise latest from one

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have two unrelated observables that have the same effect, so I wish *to observe them at the same time* and keep the code DRY.

So I effectively want to observe their streams, and when a value pops, subscribe to the latest value of only one of them, something like;

```
/* observing a change in the query values */
var userQuery$ = store$.pipe(select(fromUserStore.getUserQuery));

/* always reload the users when navigation occurs */
var navigationEvents$ = router.events.filter(
  event =>
    event instanceof NavigationEnd &&
    (event as NavigationEnd).url.endsWith("manage-users")
);
navigationEvents$
  .pipe(withLatestFrom(userQuery$), merge(userQuery$))
  .subscribe((query: QueryDefinition) =>
    store$.dispatch(new FetchUsers(query))
  );
```

Am I on the right lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as with all my `rxjs` woes, its just the ordering of things and understanding which values get poked out where. Good old verbose logging to the rescue. This was what worked:

```
 navigationEvents$
  .pipe(merge(userQuery$), withLatestFrom(userQuery$))
  .subscribe(([payload, query]) => store$.dispatch(new FetchUsers(query)));
```